# Covariant derivative as a type $(1,2)$ tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Ref. 'Core Principles of Special and General Relativity' (Luscombe) Section 14.1.3 (regarding covariant derivatives - intrinsic differential geometry)

Let $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ be two operators satisfying the covariant derivative properties (linearity, product rule, commutativity with contractions, equivalence to partial derivative for scalar fields).

> Let $\omega$ be a covariant vector field on $M$. The operation $(\nabla'_{\mu}-\nabla_{\mu})\omega_{\nu}$ effects a linear map from dual vectors to type $(0,2)$ tensors; the operator $(\nabla'_{\mu}-\nabla_{\mu})$ is therefore a type $(1,2)$ tensor.

This is slightly confusing. Vectors are also supposed to be directional derivative **operators** in a tangent space on smooth functions, and their superscript index means they're contravariant $(1,0)$ tensors. The reason I mention this is because analogously, $(\nabla'_{\mu}-\nabla_{\mu})$ is also an **operator** with a subscript index, which suggests it's a $(0,1)$ tensor.

On the other hand, this reminded me of why automorphisms are called $(1,1)$ tensors - since there's an isomorphism between the space of automorphisms and $(1,1)$ tensors. So by the same logic, is there an isomorphism between the space of $(\nabla'_{\mu}-\nabla_{\mu})$ operators and $(1,2)$ tensors? In that case, if that isomorphism is denoted by $\Theta$, then $T\equiv\Theta(\nabla'-\nabla)$ would be a $(1,2)$ tensor, but I've had no luck with defining such a $T$.

The best I can do is that it can eat one vector : $\partial_{\mu}$ and one covector : $\omega$. Where does the other covector come from?

Comment: [Also relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212195/difference-of-two-connections-is-a-tensor)

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155222/the-affine-property-of-connections-on-vector-bundles)

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: Thank you! But both of these answers are above my level. Would be grateful for a simpler explanation (or even a rough sketch of it if the actual explanation involves advanced concepts). It's my first time studying the subject and I'm trying to get used to it.

Comment: You just have to verify that the map $T : \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$ defined as $ T(X,Y) = \nabla'_XY - \nabla_XY$ is bilinear over $C^{\infty}(M)$. Therefore induce a $(1,2)$-tensor field. How can multilinear map $T$ induce a tensor field ? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722516/prove-the-curvature-tensor-is-a-tensor?noredirect=1&lq=1).